# How to handle Underscores in xml tags

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, bindy

How to handle the underscores in xml tags. Here is the code which I'm working. It was generating me the xml tag with double underscores ("__") instead of single underscore ("_"). Can anyone help me to overcome this issue.

***ConverterRoute.Java***

```
public class ConverterRoute implements RoutesBuilder {

    private static final String SOURCE_INPUT_PATH = "file://inbox?fileName=Source.txt";

    private static final String SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH = "file://outbox?fileName=file_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.xml";

    public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                try {
                    DataFormat bindyFixed = new BindyCsvDataFormat(Test.class);

                    XStreamDataFormat xStreamDataFormat = new XStreamDataFormat();
                    xStreamDataFormat.setAliases(Collections.singletonMap("TEST_INB",Test.class.getCanonicalName()));

                    from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
                            split().tokenize(System.lineSeparator()).
                            unmarshal(bindyFixed).
                            marshal(xStreamDataFormat).
                            to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH).log("Finished Transformation").end();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***CamelConfig.java***

```
@Component
public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        try {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            ConverterRoute route = new ConverterRoute();
            route.addRoutesToCamelContext(context);
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            context.stop();

        } catch (Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***Test.java***

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\|",skipField = true,name = "TEST_INB")
public class Test {

    @DataField(pos = 1,name = "ALT_NUM")
    private BigDecimal ALT_NUM;

    @DataField(pos = 2,name = "PRTNUM")
    private BigDecimal PRTNUM;

    @DataField(pos = 3,name = "UOMCOD")
    private Integer UOMCOD;

}
```

***Source.txt***

```
55158|11901|2346
55158|11101|3454
```

***OUTPUT***

***File.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>    
    <TEST__INB>
            <ALT__NUM>55158</ALT__NUM>
            <PRTNUM>11901</PRTNUM>
            <UOMCOD>2346</UOMCOD>
    </TEST__INB>
```

***Expected OUTPUT***

***File.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>    
    <TEST_INB>
            <ALT_NUM>55158</ALT_NUM>
            <PRTNUM>11901</PRTNUM>
            <UOMCOD>2346</UOMCOD>
    </TEST_INB>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XStream is internally using underscore to escape characters when producing the XML.

See FAQ:
http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#XML_double_underscores

You may try to use a custom driver (rather than the default one):

```
XmlFriendlyNameCoder nameCoder = new XmlFriendlyNameCoder("_-", "_");  
Dom4JDriver myCustomDriver = new Dom4JDriver(nameCoder);
... 
XStreamDataFormat xStreamDataFormat = new XStreamDataFormat();
xStreamDataFormat.setDriver(myCustomDriver);
```

or, if not working, maybe try with this other alternate driver:

```
DomDriver myCustomDriver = new DomDriver("UTF_8", new NoNameCoder());
```

Hope this works !

Comment: When I use Dom4JDriver it is returning class not found exception, But when I tried DomDriver I don't see any change. @TacheDeChoco

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use Xstream aliases: See for instance https://www.baeldung.com/xstream-serialize-object-to-xml